# How to assign dataframe to panel from a function return

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, panel

I have a function which returns a panel and a dataframe. For example,

```
def fo(pn,df)
  some update on pn,df
  return pn, df
```

Then I need to call fo function to update pn4 and pn3 like below,

```
pn4.loc[0], pn3.loc[0] = fo(pn,df)
```

where pn4 is a Panel4 structure and pn3 is a Panel. As far as I know, pn4.loc[0] should be a panel and pn3.loc[0] should be a dataframe. But I recieved a error message when I run such code

> NotImplementedError: cannot set using an indexer with a Panel yet!

So how can I address this error? Thanks in advance.

For futher information, I post my codes below:

```
def update(x, UC, SC, A, U): # accelerated version, examined on 07/15 

    for a in A:
        UC_old = UC.copy()
        for u in U:
            UC.loc[a,:,u] = UC_old.loc[a,:,u] - UC_old.loc[a,:,x] * UC_old.loc[a,x,u]
        SC_old = SC.copy()
        SC.loc[:,a] = SC_old.loc[:,a] + UC_old.loc[a,x,:] * (1 - SC_old.loc[x,a])

    return UC, SC


def Streaming(UC, Au, k, U, A):
    ep = 0.01
    SC = pd.DataFrame(0.0, index = U, columns = A)
    max_mg = 0    
    for x in U:
        mg = computeMG(x, UC, SC, Au, A, U)
        max_mg = mg if mg > max_mg else max_mg
    del SC
    C = []
    S = {}
    m = max_mg
    while (m <= k*max_mg):
        C.append(m)
        S[m] = []        
        m = m * (1+ep)
    print len(C)
    UCC = pd.Panel4D(dict([(c, UC.copy()) for c in C]))           
    SCC = pd.Panel(0., items = C, major_axis = U, minor_axis = A)
    for x in U:
        for c in C:
            if (computeMG(x, UCC.loc[c], SCC.loc[c], Au, A, U) > c/float(2*k)) and (len(S[c])<k):
                S[c].append(x)
                UCC.loc[c], SCC.loc[c] = update(x, UCC.loc[c], SCC.loc[c], A, U) # where the error happens
    max_val = 0
    for c in C:
        val = 0
        for u in U:
            Tsu = 0
            for a in A:
                Tsu += SCC.loc[c,u,a]
            Tsu = Tsu / float(Au.loc[u])
            val += Tsu
        if val > max_val:
            S = S[c]
            max_val = val
    return S, max_val
```

Comment: For the futher information, my real code in my python file is like `UCC.loc[c], SCC.loc[c] = update(x, UCC.loc[c], SCC.loc[c], A, U)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For dataframes and series, you can use `loc` and `iloc` (and `at` and `iat` also) to get and set.  This requires coding to make happen.  The error you are seeing

> NotImplementedError: cannot set using an indexer with a Panel yet!

Means that someone hasn't gotten around to make it happen for panels yet.

you should be able to make the assignment with

```
pn4[0], pn3[0] = fo(pn,df)
```

Comment: Yeah, `pn4[0], pn3[0] = fo(pn,df)` works. But could you tell me why `loc` will lead to the error message?

Comment: @Wedoso I stated the reason in the post.  It's meant to work just as you expected.  However, a pandas contributor hasn't yet sat down to put together the code necessary to make that happen.  Hence the "NotImplementedError", as it we have not implemented this.  And the comment, "cannot set using an indexer with a Panel yet!".  They mean it to work this way and someday it probably will.

Answer (score 0):

The return type in `fo` is dataframe; however in the last line of your code you assign `pn4.loc[0]` and `pn3.loc[0]` to dataframe objects. `pn.4loc[0]` and `pn3.loc[0]` can be Pandas Series, that's why you saw the error because indexing is .

Make your return command as `return pn.loc[0], df.loc[0]` and you probably can solve the issue.

Below is the part of  source code in [Pandas 0.15.1](http://pydoc.net/Python/pandas/0.15.1/pandas.core.indexing/) describing NonImplementError you confronted:

```
def _align_panel(self, indexer, df):
        is_frame = self.obj.ndim == 2
        is_panel = self.obj.ndim >= 3
        raise NotImplementedError("cannot set using an indexer with a Panel 
                                  yet!")
```

As you can see if dimension of frame and panel doesn't match it will raise the error.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, but if I return pn.loc[0], df.loc[0], pn.loc[0] would become a dataframe, and df.loc[0] would become a seris, which is not what I want. I would to return whole pn and df to update panel in pn4 and dataframe in pn3 in fact.

Comment: So do you just want to update pn4 and pn3, not generating new objects?

Comment: No, I don't want to generate any new object. The only thing I need to do is to update pn4 and pn3. I add my codes above. You might check them for details.